# GridDB and .NET Core Integration

Tags: .net-core, griddb

For my personal projects and to contribute to my portfolio, I developed an end to end Employee Management System. I started out by using SQL Server since I am comfortable with it.

However, I decided to transition to NoSQL and intend to use GridDB in that matter. It is because, usually, a biometric device is used for recording a timestamped data for an employee's attendance. The efficiency and optimized speed of data storage and retrieval makes GridDB a great option for this application.

However, while reading the [GridDB Documentation](https://docs.griddb.net/) I am unable to figure out if there is an integration with GridDB possible. Thank you in advance for helping me trying to figure out the issue.

PS: this is the code that I used for connecting to SQL Server:

```cs
using Dapper;

using EmployeeManagementDAL.Interface;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using EmployeeManagementModels;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace EmployeeManagementDAL
{
    public class EmployeeRepo : EmployeeRepoInterface
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source="Device Name";Initial Catalog=EmployeeManagementSystem;User ID="admin";Password="admin"";

        public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            string output_query = "SELECT [Id], [Name], [Designation], [Department] FROM Employee;";
            IDbConnection connection = null;

            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }

                List<Employee> AllEmployees = connection.Query<Employee>(output_query).ToList();
                connection.Close();

                return AllEmployees;
            }
        }

        public void addEmployee(Employee emp)
        {
            DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("@Name", emp.Name, DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("@Designation", emp.Designation, DbType.String);
            parameters.Add("@Department", emp.Department, DbType.String);

            string output_query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee] (Name, Designation, Department) VALUES (@Name, @Designation, @Department);";

            IDbConnection connection = null;

            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }

                connection.Query<Employee>(output_query, parameters);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have the same question, did you get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

GridDB has JDBC functionality, meaning you can connect via JDBC with any interface which uses SQL. If your library can connect via SQL, you should be able to use JDBC.